# PyMuPDF: AttributeError: 'Document' object has no attribute 'loadPage'

Tags: python-3.x, image, ubuntu, pdf, converters

I'm trying to convert from pdf pages to images, in order to use OCR on image.

I have Ubuntu 21.10

Python 3

```
import fitz
# read pdf file
pdf = fitz.open(file_path_name)
# load pdf page using index
page = pdf.loadPage(0)
```

The pdf is coming from scanner.

I tried to uninstall PyMuPDF, uninstall fitz and reinstall it again but still the error

```
sudo pip uninstall PyMuPDF
sudo pip uninstall fitz
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
reboot
sudo pip install PyMuPDF
```

answer

```
Collecting PyMuPDF
  Using cached PyMuPDF-1.20.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (8.9 MB)
Installing collected packages: PyMuPDF
Successfully installed PyMuPDF-1.20.0
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The PyMUPDF library has changed naming conventions from camelCase to snake_cased. As a result, calls to `loadPage()` become `load_page()`.

More details of the name updates are found in the [documentation for Deprecated Names](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/znames.html?highlight=loadpage).

Answer (score 1):

```
import fitz
# read pdf file
pdf = fitz.open(file_path_name)
# load pdf page using index
page = pdf.load_page(0)
```

Try this code it may work it worked for me.I was having a similar problem.

Comment: I fixed it, its pdf.load_page try it.

Comment: It WAS loadPage. There has been a breaking change in 1.20.0: https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/znames.html?highlight=loadpage